# Texture painting- Override zoom limit for Painting

Tags: texture-painting

In Blender2.79,on trying to zoom into the model to paint finer details,the **brush stops rendering paint when zoomed in after a limit**.

The texture is 1024x 1024.

How to override this zoom limit for painting?

[image: Paint_Zoom_Limit]

Comment: What is your clipping set to in the N panel?

Comment: Clip Panel ->Start  = 0.001(lowest value) & End = 1000 (but clipping still exists).

Comment: Have you tried 2.8 series yet to see if the same thing occurs there? I don't keep 2.79 on my machines anymore, so I cannot test to reproduce.

Comment: @ Craig D Jones -thnxs for checking .In 2.79 zoom clipping is a problem, but still usable .I don't use 2.8